# Create multiple rows based on a column containing a list of numbers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently have a table which looks like this.

```
A       Category         Code
1        A               10,30
2        B               30
3        C               20,30,40
```

Is there anyway to write a sql statement that would get me

```
ID       Category        Code
1        A               10
1        A               30
2        B               30
3        C               20
3        C               30
3        C               40
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNNEST` with `SPLIT` function...

```
select a, category, s_code
from my_data, unnest(split(code, ',')) as s_code
```

| a | category | s_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 1 | A | 30 |
| 2 | B | 30 |
| 3 | C | 20 |
| 3 | C | 30 |
| 3 | C | 40 |